# How to create a new variable and use it in std::tie at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there a good way to use `std::tie` and create a new variable in one go? In other words, if a function returns an `std::tuple` and we want to ultimately break up the result into individual components, is there a way to do these assignments without defining variables beforehand?

For example, consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int) {}
};
struct Bar{};

std::tuple <Foo,Bar> example() {
    return std::make_tuple(Foo(1),Bar()); 
}

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar {};

    // Without std::tie
    {
        auto foo_bar = example();
        auto foo = std::get<0>(std::move(foo_bar));
        bar = std::get<1>(std::move(foo_bar));
    }

    // With std::tie
    #if 0
    {
        // Error: no default constructor
        Foo foo;
        std::tie(foo,bar) = example();
    }
    #endif

}
```

Basically, the function `example` returns a tuple.  We already have a variable of type `Bar` that we want to assign into, but we need a new variable of type `Foo`.  Without `std::tie`, we don't need to create a dummy instance of `Foo`, but the code requires us to put everything into a `std::tuple` first and then divide it.  With `std::tie`, we have to allocate a dummy `Foo` first, but we don't have a default constructor to do so.  Really, we're pretending that the constructors for `Foo` are complicated, so creating a dummy value first is undesirable.  Ultimately, we'd just like to assign into both `foo` and `bar`, but want to do this assignment and allocate memory for `Foo` at the same time.

Comment: my head hurts reading the code, which is a sure sign that simpler logic is called for. Short answer is no. returning a tuple of values is a very efficient way to return and allocate. tie:: is just there to unpack values. If you must do this, consider tie-ing to a `boost::optional<Foo>`

Comment: The fact that `Bar` contains a `Foo` seems to be a setup for a failure. Once you divorce (extract) `Foo` from `Bar`, that 50% of `Bar` becomes "valid but potentially indeterminate / not otherwise specified".

Comment: One way to work around the need to separate them is for every other class that used to split a `Foo` from a `Bar` to simply accept a `Bar` and use its member `Foo`, or to keep `Bar` alive and pass around references to `Foo`.

Comment: There was a related discussion about a potential proposal related to this problem, check it out here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/4yWRnzX7J7Y

Comment: @RichardHodges Yeah...  This is ugly, but the simplest way to get the point across.  Believe it or not, this comes up when writing lenses for nested structures.  Basically, we dive deep into some nested series of structures, grab what we need, and return it.  With copy semantics, it's clean.  Without them, we end up playing weird games moving memory around while preserving the ability to compose lenses.  Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: The function 'f' is logically redundant. It's purpose is to simply move the foo from a bar. The references to bar could simply be r-value references and it would still work. Indeed the operation of moving the foo out is trivial. Why have the function at all? It seems to me that you're looking for a solution to an artificial problem.

Comment: Because 'memory allocation' typically refers to dynamic memory allocation I rephrased the question in terms of variable definition/creation. Can I suggest you cut down your example? I think a lot of stuff is unnecessary. I believe the essence of what you are after can be boiled down to [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6f9774a8f653f9e).

Comment: @LucDanton Thanks for the suggestion.  That's a much better way to write things.  I've revised the setup.

Comment: I hope at some point, the language will be updated to this:  tie(auto a, auto b) = funcTuple(x);

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61499/a-tuple-unpacking-macro-that-approximates-python-elegance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@MikaelPersson had the right link.  Basically, there's no great way to do this.  Though, there are some clever ways based on N3802.  Namely, use

```
// This comes from the N3802 proposal for C++
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
    using Indices =
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>;
    return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), Indices{});
}
```

Then, write

```
// With compose
{
    auto foo = apply([&bar](auto && foo,auto && bar_) {
        bar=std::move(bar_);
        return std::move(foo);
    }, example());
}
```

And, yes, this whole thing is ugly, but the situation did come up in some instance I had.  Nevertheless, as @MikaelPersson's link shows, this is a general issue and not one fully resolved yet.

Answer (score 43):

This feature is called [structured bindings](https://skebanga.github.io/structured-bindings/) in C++17. Very welcome addition!

Sample usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1, 'a', 2.3);

    // unpack the tuple into individual variables declared at the call site
    auto [ i, c, d ] = tuple;

    std::cout << "i=" << i << " c=" << c << " d=" << d << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Tested in GCC 7.2 with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Awesome feature.